# Включение в список

Tags: python, list, терминология

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]> Подскажите, пожалуйста, что представляет собой понятие "Включение в список"(если рассматривать его на практике). "Включение в список" и "генераторы списка" одно и то же?

Comment: Чаще его всё же называют "списковым включением". Генератор это другое, генераторы "ленивые". Синтаксис похож, а результат разный. У одного список, а у другого генератор на выходе.

Comment: https://smartiqa.ru/blog/python-list-comprehension?ysclid=ltrodw3zta460918115   а тут пишут, что списковое включение и генератор списка одно и то же. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, годные статьи, литературу по данной теме...

Comment: @PYTHON_KA, если генератор списка - это с квадратными скобками (а не с круглыми), то да, это одно и то же.

Comment: поняла вас. спасибо...А вот ещё вопрос: в списковом включении тоже может использоваться condition, как в генераторах?

Comment: Да, может. Например так: `lst = [i*i for i in range(10) if i%2]`. Или так: `lst = [i if i in 'aeiou' else ' ' for i in input()]`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)